# Solr Search word proximity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

I am using sunspot gem for the search functionality in rails app.
I have issue in word proximity in solr search. 
Example i am searching for "Hello World", solr give me the proper result for the search.
But in first document "Hello World" string is appears only once and in second document it appears two times.

but i want is if the string appears more in any document will come at top and string appears less come after the top result.

Help will be appreciate. Thanku

Answer (score 2):

If your search field (I'll call it keywords) has **omitNorms="true"** means that the number of times the search term matches the keywords no longer matters. So set omitNorms to false in the **schema.xml**.

If you are using edismax the default boost of each field is 1, but you can boost more a specific field using caret (^). So if you want to have multiple matches, with search terms in the keywords field, to be shown much higher up in the search results you have to boost with an high factor and sort by score desc (default).

```
adjust_solr_params do |params|
  params[:fq] = "keywords_text:(your terms)^15"
end
```

Comment: I look into my configuration file, omitNorms are already set as "false".       solr have functionality call "term frequency". I found one documentation regarding these.                                                                                       @Duccio Giovannelli, can you please have a look.  [How are documents scored](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ)